# Postfix - Check and modify email body before message gets sent

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I have multiple SMTP relays set up each with their own domain. I was wondering how I could make Postfix modify an email body before it gets sent out.

Before the email gets sent each email should be checked for `www.google.com/redirect/` in the body and if it's present switch it to `www.$(hostname)/redirect/`

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen postfix content filter http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html
There are ways to either pipe your messages to a script or send them to a script using the smtp protocol (more complex but more robust). We used this method to query a db and add account id's to the subject of incoming messages. It may be helpful to you.